laravel 11 React Breeze return null and return data at same time
when i log as admin i got data from data base when i log as tenant the data is null.
i create table where user can click name and go to show page to show the profile of other user but my problem is when i click the name as admin i got some data when i log as tenent i got null value,
i try to dd() the the user form userController show but the  connection in admin has value when i log as tenant the connection is null pls help me thank you. I'm beginner in laravel 11 for more details just comment i very appreciated
admin dd
tenant dd
Link @inertiajs/react 
// admin side
 <Link href={route("user.edit",row.id)} >Edit</Link>
// tenant side 
 <Link href={route("User.show",row.id)} >{row.id}</Link>


//userConnetroller 
 public function show(User $user){
        
        if(Auth::user()->type ==="tenant"){
            dd($user);
            return inertia("Tenant/Show", [
                'Owner' =>new UsersResource($user),
            ]);
        }
        if(Auth::user()->type ==="admin"){
            dd($user);
            return inertia("Profile/Show", [
                'User' => new UsersResource($user),
            ]);
        }
    }
//UsersResource
 public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        //only see post
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "name" => $this->name,
            "email" => $this->email,
            "address" => $this->address,
            "type" => $this->type,
            "status" => $this->status,
            "contact_Number" => $this->contact_Number,
            "Facebook" => $this->Facebook,
            "BH_name" => $this->BH_name,
            "created_at" => (new Carbon( $this->created_at))->format("Y-m-D"),
            "updated_at" => (new Carbon( $this->updated_at))->format("Y-m-D"),
        ];
    }

//admin and tenant meddleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (Auth::user()->type === 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('/Admin/Dashboard');
    }
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (Auth::user()->type === 'tenant') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('/Tenant/Dashboard');
    }


data receiver react 
//tenant receiver
function Show({auth,Owner}) {

  const data = Owner.data;

//admin receiver
function Show({auth,User}) {

  const data = User.data;


